# React TypeScript iterating over array full of objects using Array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Currently, I am working on my first TypeScript project using React. However, I don't know TypeScript and planned to focus on its static types later at some point, meanwhile preparing the whole structure in regular JS. This React app connects with my personal API and fetches data from there. In regular JS I would normally fetch data in useEffect hook and add the fetched data using spread operator like that `setSomeData([...response.data])`, but it warned me `Type any[] is not assignable to never[]` so I had to do this instead `setSomeData(response.data);`.

Second major problem is that when I want to populate this data from array inside of the component I am not able to compile the project since I get following error `property make doesn't exist on type never`

React Component:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

import carsService from "../services/cars.service";

function Main() {

  const [vehiclesList, setVehiclesList] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    carsService
      .getCars()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        return setVehiclesList(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <div className="makes-list">
        {vehiclesList.map((vehicle, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <p>{vehicle.make}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Object Model:

```
const carSchema = new Schema(
  {
    carId: { type: String, unique: true, require: true },
    make: { type: String, unique: true, require: true },
    models: [
      {
        name: { type: String, unique: true },
        reviews: [
          {
            Version: { type: String, require: true },
            Year: { type: Number, require: true },
            Engine: { type: String, requite: true },
            General: { type: String, require: true },
            Pros: { type: String, require: true },
            Cons: { type: String, require: true },
            User: { type: String, require: true },
            Date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: {
      createdAt: "createdAt",
      updatedAt: "updatedAt",
    },
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the TypeScript interfaces for the `vehiclesList`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import carsService from '../services/cars.service';

interface Review {
  Version: string;
  Year: number;
  Engine: string;
  General: string;
  Pros: string;
  Cons: string;
  User: string;
  Date: Date;
}

interface Model {
  name: string;
  reviews: Review[];
}

interface Car {
  carId: string;
  make: string;
  models: Model[];
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

function Main() {
  const [vehiclesList, setVehiclesList] = useState<Car[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    carsService
      .getCars()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        return setVehiclesList(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <div className="makes-list">
        {vehiclesList.map((vehicle, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <p>{vehicle.make}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a life-saver. Everything works as it supposed to work and I have also learned something new. :)